# Camera app features disabled with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-camera

When using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with android Intent:

```
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, it.uri)
    intentLauncher.launch(intent)
```

My app opens camera activity as expected, but it seems to be a dumbed-down version of the original camera app. For example on my Samsung S20+ device, I do not get the ability to scan documents when taking pictures, and if I go into settings of launched activity, Intelligent features are disabled and it says that "Intelligent features only work with the rear camera in Photo mode"

If I use INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA, then all the intelligent features work, but this mode doesn't return me back to my app after taking a picture.

Is there a way to achieve ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with enabled additional camera features?

Comment: "My app opens camera activity as expected, but it seems to be a dumbed-down version of the original camera app" -- there are hundreds of possible camera apps that your `Intent` could launch, from both pre-installed and user-installed apps. How any of those apps respond to your `Intent` is up to the developers of those apps. There is no requirement that they offer any particular feature set that might be available when starting the camera app in other ways.

Comment: "Is there a way to achieve ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with enabled additional camera features?" -- there is nothing in the Android SDK for this.